# ¿Como convertir un dato de tipo double a int?

Tags: java

Quiero multiplicar estos valores.

```
int result,quantity = 10;
double quantity_col = 3.500;
result = quantity*quantity_col;
```

pero el ide eclipse me lo subraya y me da un error.

> java.lang.Error cannot convert from double to int

Comment: Deben ser del mismo tipo de dato.

Comment: oye y no existe un metodo para convertir datos de float a int asi como el integer.parseint o algo asi?

Comment: Busca sobre como hacer cast de valores, ¿por otro lado por qué usar distintos tipos de datos?

Comment: muy amables todos,son tan buenos que no sabia de que forma agradecerles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La variable `result` es de tipo `int`, por lo que, al haber un `double` en tu multiplicación, hace bien Eclipse en indicarte el error, pues en una multiplicación entre un `int` y un `double`, el resultado obtenido es un `double` y, como tal, debe almacenarse en una variable de ese tipo. Tu código, entonces, debe quedar así:

```
int quantity = 10;
double result;
double quantity_col;
result = quantity * quantity_col;
```

PD: siempre declara un atributo por línea, para una mejor lectura del programa.

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que debería ser marcada como "correcta".

Answer (score 2):

```
 double result,quantity = 10;
    double quantity_col = 3.500;
    result = quantity*quantity_col;
```

Comment: lee por favor [answer]... y si tiene que ser entero si o si?

Comment: oigan disculpenme pero yo ya sabia hacerlo de la forma en que modificaste el codigo gracias,pero entonces mi profesor esta mal? dice que se deben convertir valores de float a int de tal forma como se hace de string a int con un integer o un metodo similar

Comment: sin embargo confirmenme si de todos modos explico lo que ustedes sugieren

Comment: @mauricio El error lo puedes solucionar haciendo un casting de esta manera: `result = quantity* (int)quantity_col;`. Sin embargo, posiblemente haya pérdida de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir un valor de tipo **double** a **int** tienes que hacer uso de lo que se conoce como **casting** o de **clases** que Java provee para realizar conversiones en tu caso el código te debe quedar como sigue:

```
result = Integer.parseInt(quantity*quantity_col);
```

Otra opción es hacer casting:

```
result = (int) quantity*quantity_col;
```

Y estas son las dos formas en las que puedes convetir un double a int.